# google Chrome extension, add the tab to context menu

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

How to add another option to the context menu that appears by right-clicking on the icon expansion?

I try this:

```
function addMenu(title) {
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
        title: title,
        contexts: ["all"],
        onclick: function() { console.log(1)}
    });
}

addMenu('Log out');
```

I receive an error:

Unchecked runtime.lastError while running contextMenus.create: Extensions using event pages must pass an id parameter to chrome.contextMenus.create

Who had such problems? Can you help?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As the error message says, you're using an [event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) and thus must provide an `id` to `chrome.contextMenus.create` to use it in the [onClicked listener](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#event-onClicked):

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
    id: "some-command",
    title: "some title",
    contexts: ["all"]
});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function(info, tab) {
    if (info.menuItemId == "some-command") {
        console.log("yay!");
    }
});
```

This is because the event pages are unloaded after a few seconds of inactivity, so inline callbacks can't be used. Whereas `onClicked` listener is tracked by Chrome so that the event page is autoloaded when needed.