# Extensions using event pages or Service Workers must pass an id parameter to chrome.contextMenus.create

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, contextmenu, browser-extension

I'm writing a simple browser extension. I have a problem with context menu. I want that the menu I want to add is accessible only on textarea or text input and after the user select some text inside these two type of elements. I'm using this code but I always get this error

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError: Extensions using event pages or Service Workers must pass an id parameter to chrome.contextMenus.create
```

This is my actual code

```js
const textTranslate = (info, tab) => {
  console.log(info, tab);
  //API call
  //fetch(...).then().then();
}

const parentMenu = browser.contextMenus.create({
  id: 'live-translate',
  title: 'LiveTranslate',
  contexts: ['editable']
});

browser.contextMenus.create({
  title: 'Translate',
  contexts: ['selection'],
  parentId: parentMenu,
});

browser.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(textTranslate);
```

Since I will do an api call to do the needed operations on the selected text, how I can replace the selection with the response of the api call?

Comment: As the error message says you need to add any unique `id` in your second create() call.

Comment: ok, after this how I can replace the selected text?I need a content script or I can do replacement directly from the background script?

Comment: It's another problem. One thing at a time.

Comment: some one has answer the question,[here‘s the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32719354/3618679)